# Replace a child node in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm manipulating a tree of data. From any given node, I might need to add a child node, which is returned from a RESTful server. The data starts out looking something like this…

```
[{ "text":"Apples", "id":1, "childNodes":[] },
 { "text":"Boxes", "id":2, "childNodes":[] },
 { "text":"Cups", "id":3, "childNodes":[] }]
```

then I do a post of "id:1" which returns…

```
[{ "text":"Apples", "id":1, "childNodes":[
    { "text":"first Apple", "id":'1a', "childNodes":[] },
    { "text":"second Apple", "id":'1b', "childNodes":[] },
    { "text":"third Apple", "id":'1c', "childNodes":[] }
  ]
}]
```

… which is a complete replacement for the requested node. I have Angular properly laying out the model, accepting data changes, posting those changes to the server, and accepting that last JSON blob. Awesome. But I'm not sure how to update the $scope with the new data. My View looks something like this…

```
<div ng-repeat="node in data.nodes" >
  <p>{{node.text}}</p>
  <button ng-click="addLoopInstance(node)">Add child nodes</button>
</div>
```

and the controller…

```
function SurveyController($scope, sampleService) {

    $scope.addLoopInstance = function(node) {
        sampleService.post({ id: node.id }, function(response, getResponseHeaders) {
            // this doesn't work
            node = response;
            // neither does this
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                node = response;
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance, the Angular documentation is… wanting… but I've found the user base to be exceptionally helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `node.childNodes=response.childNodes` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just going off of what you said, I built a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VXxqM/3/

Two things about this though, your `addLoopInstance()`, if it does return:

```
[{ "text":"Apples", "id":1, "childNodes":[
    { "text":"first Apple", "id":'1a', "childNodes":[] },
    { "text":"second Apple", "id":'1b', "childNodes":[] },
    { "text":"third Apple", "id":'1c', "childNodes":[] }
  ]
}]
```

Then you need to reference the child nodes that you are replacing:

```
node.childNodes = response[0].childNodes;
```

Secondly, I don't know if you are just leaving stuff out for simplicity sake, but your original `ng-repeat` loop doesn't address the childNodes, so as you have it, there is no way to tell if indeed it is being updated.  Anyways, check out the fiddle and see what I did to get it working.

Comment: Yup, I was just confused by which level of the response I was trying to insert. Thank you for pointing me in the right way.